# Is webmin advisable to run on arm based embedded system in debian?

Tags: linux, web, embedded, iot, webmin

Looking forward to imlement web based system which will allow following things to be able to do:

1. To manage the web-based system configuration
2. Possible to configure operating system internals, such as users, disk quotas, services or configuration files, as well as modify and control open source apps
3. Custom modules to configure propitiatory hardware functions

Answer (score 0):

You could go with Webmin/[Virtualmin](https://www.virtualmin.com/) combination. It can do nearly all mentioned things. It has both free GPL and Pro version with extended functionality.

You just need to run `install.sh` script to have GPL version installed.

```
wget http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh
```

Later, if you'd like you could purchase the Pro version.